# if field end_date exists update end_date else add start_date and end_date fields

Tags: elasticsearch

This is the document:

```
{
  "start_date": 2017-01-01  
  "end_date": 2017-01-02,
}
```

Say that this is my value:

```
2017-01-03
```

I want to update the document with this condition:

```
if end_date field exists in document:
    document.end_date = 2017-01-03
else:
    document.end_date = 2017-01-03
    document.start_date = 2017-01-03
```

Updated document:

```
{
  "start_date": 2017-01-01  
  "end_date": 2017-01-03
}
```

Is this possible with elasticsearch scripting languages?